# IBM MAXIMO: How to create PO from PR with REST API

Tags: vba, rest, api, maximo

in IBM Maximo 7.6.0.8 I would like to create PO from a PR using REST API and VBA (HTTP requests).
My code is:

```
Dim PostData() As Byte
Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

PostData = "~date=23-08-2018"
PostData = StrConv(PostData, vbFromUnicode)

myheader = myheader & "x-http-method-override: createPOsFromPR" & vbNewLine
myheader = myheader  & "Content-Type: application/json" & vbCrLf

IE.Navigate "https://host:port/maxrest/rest/mbo/pr/123", 0, "myIE", PostData, myheader
```

But I get Error 500. Authentication is not the problem.
In general I would like to be albe to copy (assign) PR lines to POs and RFQs.
Is this the way to do this? Does someone has working solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Is this really how the documentation recommends you interact with the API rather than xmlhttp? I would have expected a POST XHR.

Comment: I have tried with POST XHR:
    `
    PostData = "statusdate=23-08-2018"
    PostData = StrConv(PostData, vbFromUnicode)
    
    myheader = myheader & "x-http-method-override: createPOsFromPR" & vbNewLine
    myheader = myheader & "Content-Type: application/json;"
     
    objHTTP.Open "POST", "https://url/maxrest/rest/mbo/PR/123", False
    objHTTP.send (PostData)`
Still not working.

Comment: Hi, 1) What happened? 2) that is not how you would add headers to xhr. You would use .setrequestheader "myheader","pair"  3) Do you have the link to the documentation? Worth reading it and sharing here if possible.

Comment: 1) No result is produced, I should try con construct a better POST XHR I guess.. In other cases when I need HTTP POST this worked. 2) https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSANHD_7.6.1/com.ibm.mif.doc/gp_intfrmwk/rest_api/c_rest_service_query.html This is not exactly the same but there is no clear documentation on this subject. Search for x-http-method-override

Comment: There may be other methods I haven't seen :-) I will look at the documentation.

Comment: I think you need .SetRequestHeader. Now, which of the following is the method you are trying to apply for creation? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/search/create%20po?scope=SSANHD_7.6.1

Comment: Yes, I did it with .setRequestHeader and I think my code before wasn't passing the header. So now I get Error 500 just like with InternetExplorer.  In the search there is no documentation of my scenario. The closest think is the link I get posted.

Comment: This link also is a good one: 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSANHD_7.6.1/com.ibm.mif.doc/gp_intfrmwk/rest_api/c_rest_service_update.html

Comment: Yes... I had seen that one but is that what you are trying to do? If so, your post body needs to look like that and that is what goes in the .send body

Comment: The idea is the same but the action I want to perform is different - "createPOsFromPR" so the post body is also different. For the post pody I do reference to this page: https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/7609/maximocore/businessobjects/psdi/app/pr/PR.html search for "createPOsFromPR"

Answer (score 1):

You could use the New REST API that allows you to directly call an automation script.
You'd add the PR number and date as request parameters and use them in the script to call
the `PR.createPOsFromPR` method.

Your call would look like this:

```
http://maximohost/maximo/oslc/script/genPOsScript?prnum=ABC&date=2019-11-21
```

You might want to add the site as param too because PR is a site level object.

You can see an example here:
https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/restguide/Maximo_Nextgen_REST_API.html#_automation_scripts

Comment: Hello, thank you for the effort. The problem is that I don't have access to Maximo Admin Panel (I guess) where scripting happens. I cannot do changes to the system.

Comment: @Rhye Unfortunately, it seems that the PR service doesn't expose a REST accessible Web Method for CreatePOsFromPR. You can get the allowed actions with a similar call:
http://maximohost/maximo/oslc/os/mxpr?oslc.where=prnum="PR1000"&oslc.select=allowedactions

Ref.: https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/restguide/Maximo_Nextgen_REST_API.html#_actions

Comment: IBM has completely messed up their documentation system, breaking the helpful link you provided all these years ago. Do you happen to have a local copy stored somewhere?